# WebApiApplication running in Azure keeps restarting

Tags: c#, web-applications

I have a WebApiApplication running on Azure on a Web App App service. One of the API endpoints starts off a process that could take a minute or 2 to complete. This process is started as a Task and the endpoint immediately returns, there is no need to wait for the process to finish.

The problem I'm having is that sometimes. this process seems to disappear before it's finished.

I've added lots of logging which shows that everything is working fine until the logging just stops there are no errors logged by the try/catch sections. I also have logging in the Application_Start() section. I can see that when this process stops logging I also get a log line indication that the Application_Start() method has been called.

So it seems that something is causing the web and to restart, but I don't know what. I can't find anything indicating a restart in the Azure logs. The restart can happen at different points of the process (could not happen at all and everything completes as it should). There doesn't seem to be any consistency with timing either, it could be a couple of seconds between restarts or a couple of minutes.

What could be causing the app to restart?

Example API controller - in the real app the `StuffProcessor` is a separate public class, I've just made is a private class here for simplicity.

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace testApp.Controllers
{
    public class TestController : ApiController
    {
        private class StuffProcessor
        {
            public void Run()
            {
                //do some stuff here that could take a couple of minutes
                //calls are made to download files from Azure blob storage and process them
            }
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("api/DoSomeStuff")]
        public string DoSomeStuff()
        {
            var stuffProcessor = new StuffProcessor();
            Task.Run(() => stuffProcessor.Run());

            return "Started";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have here an article why it can restart: https://azure.github.io/AppService/2021/09/16/App-Service-Restarts.html . As u can see many things may cause it.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I'm sure that there is no manual or API restarts going on. I did try dissabling the Auto-Heal, but that didn't seem to help.